# Why is PHP $_SESSION returning empty on different PHP files?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm trying to carry randomly generated numbers from one page to another in PHP using $_SESSION. Every time I `print_r($_SESSION)` on the second page the array comes back empty. But when I `print_r($_SESSION)` on the first page it shows all the data that has been added throughout the script.

Here's the code I've got:

pageOne.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!-- Some HTML -->
<?php
$counter = 0;
while (counter <= 9) {
    genData($counter);
    $counter++;
}
// genData function
function genData($count) {
    $number = rand(1, 10);
    $_SESSION[$count] = $number;
}
// print_r() to check data has been added
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

pageTwo.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// print_r to make sure data has been carried forward
print_r($_SESSION);
// unset and destroy session
session_unset();
session_destroy();
?>
```

The output from the print_r() on pageOne would look something like this:

> Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6
>   [7] => 7 [8] => 8 [9] => 9 )

Whereas on pageTwo it would just be this:

> Array ( )

I've been using PHP 7.1.0 and hosting a local PHP server through atom.io, I've also tried this on c9.io and XAMPP but I still get the same problem. I've also checked the session id's and they are always the same.

I'm not sure if its a problem with my PHP config or with my code.

Comment: on `pageTwo.php` you are printing `$_SESSION` . You should `print_r($_SESSION[0])` for example or `print_r($_SESSION['0']);` not sure.

Comment: Use the browser developer tools to determine if the session ID cookie changes. Check the session directory to see if files are being generated and contain data.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos print_r($_SESSION) should output the hole array ...

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos How can it be possible that an empty array has an item on key 0?

Comment: @mr.void Oh ok, that is a helpful tip - didn't know that!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález What do you mean? If we suppose $_SESSION variables work properly, if he `print_r()` he will have back the results.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos You claim that `print_r($_SESSION)` produces `Array ()` but `print_r($_SESSION[0])` will print the entire array. That can't happen.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Oh no we got confused there. I didn't know that i could print all variables of $_SESSION by calling `print_r($_SESSION);` - i thought i always had to indicate the index.

Comment: are the two pages in the same directory?

Comment: Step 1: Run the page1 function and populate your data, then disable your page one function and rerun the page - it should still have the data set on run 1, is this so? If this is not so then this means your issue is your session storage rather than the transition between pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on pageOne.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!-- Some HTML -->
<?php
$counter = 0;
while ($counter <= 9) {
    genData($counter);
    $counter++;
}
// genData function
function genData($count) {
    $number = rand(1, 10);
    $_SESSION[$count] = $number;
}
// print_r() to check data has been added
print_r($_SESSION);
```